# How to add tab bar to tableview but not detailed view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6, tabview

My storyboard goes from nav controller -> tableview controller -> detailed view controller.

I want to add a tab bar at the bottom of just the table view but every time I try and embed a controller in a tab view, the white space always goes on the detailed view, but only the tableview has the button. I want the tableview to only have the white space and button and nothing on the detailed view. Hopefully this is enough to get what I am looking for, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your detail view controller, check Hide Bottom Bar on Push

[image: Like this]

Comment: I added a picture of how text is still underneath the bar after I checked hide bottom bar on push

Comment: using UITabbarController or just a UIToolbar?